# Calculating Average Value of JSONB array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, json, array, string, integer

I have a column called "value" in my "answers" table.

```
|  value  |
|---------|
|  [1,2]  |
|   [1]   |
| [1,2,3] |
```

The type of "value" is "jsonb".

I want to get the average value of each array in each row:

```
SELECT avg(value) AS avg_value
FROM answers
```

But this doesn't work because avg() is not a jsonb function. I've tried:

```
SELECT avg(value::integer[]) as avg_value
FROM answers
```

i.e. tried to cast the jsonb arrays into integer arrays and then taking the avg, but I get the following error: "cannot cast type jsonb to integer[]. null".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to unnest the JSON array with `jsonb_array_elements`.**

You can do this in a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT AVG(value::decimal(18,5))
   FROM jsonb_array_elements(value)
  ) AS avg_value
FROM answers;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6nPgQryxrjdTSocRAiPdLF/0)

Comment: Could you please explain what the decimal(18,5) does? Specifically the numbers 18 and 5.

Comment: Precision and scale. I just picked anything, you could convert to `decimal(5,2)` if you like, or even `float`

Comment: Thank you for your help!